# How to create PIN input with 4 EditTexts and addTextChangedListener?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I am trying to create a security code login page with 4 EdtiText cells. Basically I want the cell to be restricted to 1 digit, and as soon as the user types in a digit, it jumps to the next EditText. When we reach the 4th and last cell, I want the app to automatically check the entire code and change activity if code is correct.

Here is my XML:

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_30sdp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_40sdp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_40sdp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

 <EditText
                            style="@style/LoginSecurityCode"
                            android:id="@+id/et_login_code_1"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:nextFocusRight="@+id/et_login_code_2"/>

 <EditText
                            style="@style/LoginSecurityCode"
                            android:id="@+id/et_login_code_2"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:nextFocusRight="@+id/et_login_code_3"/>

 <EditText
                            style="@style/LoginSecurityCode"
                            android:id="@+id/et_login_code_3"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:nextFocusRight="@+id/et_login_code_4"/>

 <EditText
                            style="@style/LoginSecurityCode"
                            android:id="@+id/et_login_code_1"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:nextFocusRight="@+id/et_login_code_2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and my style for each EditText:

```
<style name="LoginSecurityCode">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/_40sdp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">@dimen/_8sdp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/_4sdp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginStart">@dimen/_8sdp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_20ssp</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#50000000</item>
    <item name="android:hint">@string/label_login_code_placeholder</item>
    <item name="android:importantForAutofill" tools:ignore="NewApi">no</item>
    <item name="android:inputType">numberDecimal</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:maxLength">1</item>
</style>
```

It is important to note that I do not want to do the noob way with 4 different addTextChangedListeners, I want to find a smart way with minimum lines of Java/Kotlin.

Comment: Why don't you add your own keypad, and use input on Textview, rather than Edittext?
Although if  you continue with the current approach, then you need to add 4 watchers

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I think creating my own keypad is actually a better way and gives me more freedom in customisation. I'll also block the soft keyboard from Manifest to prevent unwanted overlays.

Comment: I can give you all the things if you want, I have created one

Comment: Thanks but not needed because I want to do this as an exercise. I'll create a RecycleView with GrildLayoutManager for the keypad and use LiveData to mange the real-time key presses.

Comment: Check the following link http://lomza.totem-soft.com/pin-input-view-in-android/ This might help!